# Powershell script to deploy another script to multiple servers

Tags: powershell, deployment

I have a Powershell script already created. Now I want this script to be deployed into 20 different servers. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) for system administration questions like these:

- [Execute program on remote computer using PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/questions/77585/execute-program-on-remote-computer-using-powershell)
- [Powershell Remoting: Howto Run a Comand on multiple Machines with individual Parameters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/126432/powershell-remoting-howto-run-a-comand-on-multiple-machines-with-individual-par)
- MSDN: [Windows PowerShell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Adding remote machine to AD via Powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/593152/adding-remote-machine-to-ad-via-powershell)